# Insert distance in kilometers and increase text font in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The code below calculates the distance in meters from one property to another. Note that the distance is in meters, but in addition to generating the distance in meters, I would like to generate the distance in `kilometers` (Km) as well. So, considering the example in the image below, it could look like this:

```
Road distance calculation: 24751 meters (approximately 24 Km)
```

Also, if possible, I would like the font size of the text `Road distance calculation: Road distance calculation: 24751 meters`

Code executable below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)

k=3
set_key( "AIzaSyBD6kgTlgcTa6iwLwoWtKrKQI6QNodEkmo")

function.cl<-function(Filter1,Filter2){
  
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Latitude = c(-23.8, 
   -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.4, -23.5), Longitude = c(-49.6, 
  -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6, -49.4, -49.2), 
  cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L,3L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
  
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8666666666667, -23.85, -23.45
  ), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, -49.35, -49.3), cluster = c(1, 
  2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,]
  
  #Table to join
  data_table <- df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster, df[,c("cluster","Properties")], toString)
  
  
  # Map for route
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust>0) & nrow(df_spec_prop>0)) {
    df2<-google_directions(origin = df_spec_clust[,1:2], 
                           destination = df_spec_prop[,2:3], mode = "driving")
    
    distance_road <- sum(as.numeric(direction_steps(df2)$distance$value)) 

  } else {
    distance_road <- NA
  }
  

  return(list(
    "distance_road" = distance_road,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          textOutput("distance_road")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel(""))
                            
                          )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })

  
  observeEvent(k, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(c(k,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))})

    output$distance_road <- renderText({
    paste0("Road distance calculation: ",Modelcl()$distance_road," meters")
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
# library(googleway)

k=3
# set_key( "AIzaSyBD6kgTlgcTa6iwLwoWtKrKQI6QNodEkmo")

function.cl<-function(Filter1,Filter2){
    list(distance_road = 24751)
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
               "Cl", 
               tabPanel("Solution",
                        sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                                
                                selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                                selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                                textOutput("distance_road"),
                                tags$style(HTML(
                                    '
                                    #distance_road {
                                        font-size: 2rem;
                                    }
                                    '
                                ))
                            ),
                            mainPanel(
                                tabsetPanel(      
                                    tabPanel(""))
                            )
                        )
                )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    Modelcl<-reactive({
        function.cl(input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(k, {
        abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
        updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                          choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
    }) 
    
    observeEvent(c(k,input$Filter1),{
        abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
        updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                          choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))})
    
    output$distance_road <- renderText({
        paste0(
            "Road distance calculation: ", Modelcl()$distance_road," meters ", 
            "(approximately ", floor(Modelcl()$distance_road/1000), " Km)"
        )
    })
    
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

1. I faked your `function.cl` function so it always returns `24751`. Change it back in your real case.
2. Change the `font-size: 2rem;` to whatever font size you want.
3. Km calculation is added.
4. Try not to post your key token in the question next time. It is insecure.

[image]

Comment: I have a question, for example, if 300 meters appear, approximately 0 Km will appear, would you not be able to adjust this, that is, put 0,3 Km?

Comment: @Antonio you would need to change `floor` to `round`. `round(Modelcl()$distance_road/1000, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

We can increase the size of the font by surrounding the `textOutput` with a div and using the style argument, for example:

```
div(textOutput("distance_road"), style = "font-size: 20px;")
```

For displaying the distance in km we can use the `glue` function like this:

```
  output$distance_road <- renderText({
    glue::glue("Road distance calculation: {Modelcl()$distance_road} meters (approximately {round(Modelcl()$distance_road / 1000)} km)")
  })
```

app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)

k <- 3
set_key("your_api_key")

function.cl <- function(Filter1, Filter2) {
  df <- structure(list(
    Properties = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Latitude = c(
      -23.8,
      -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.4, -23.5
    ), Longitude = c(
      -49.6,
      -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6, -49.4, -49.2
    ),
    cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L)
  ), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")


  df1 <- structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8666666666667, -23.85, -23.45), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, -49.35, -49.3), cluster = c(
    1,
    2, 3
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


  # specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1, ]
  df_spec_prop <- df[df$Properties == Filter2, ]

  # Table to join
  data_table <- df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Properties)), ]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster, df[, c("cluster", "Properties")], toString)


  # Map for route
  if (nrow(df_spec_clust > 0) & nrow(df_spec_prop > 0)) {
    df2 <- google_directions(
      origin = df_spec_clust[, 1:2],
      destination = df_spec_prop[, 2:3], mode = "driving"
    )

    distance_road <- sum(as.numeric(direction_steps(df2)$distance$value))
  } else {
    distance_road <- NA
  }


  return(list(
    "distance_road" = distance_road,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
    "Cl",
    tabPanel(
      "Solution",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"), ""),
          selectInput("Filter2", label = h4("Select the cluster property designated above"), ""),
          div(textOutput("distance_road"), style = "font-size: 20px;")
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Modelcl <- reactive({
    function.cl(input$Filter1, input$Filter2)
  })


  observeEvent(k, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session, "Filter1",
      choices = sort(unique(abc$cluster))
    )
  })

  observeEvent(c(k, input$Filter1), {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session, "Filter2",
      choices = sort(unique(abc$Properties))
    )
  })

  output$distance_road <- renderText({
    glue::glue("Road distance calculation: ", Modelcl()$distance_road, " meters ", "(approximately {round(Modelcl()$distance_road / 1000)} km)")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```